# Allocate large blocks of contiguous memory - do or don't?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have always been convinced that it is not a good practice to allocate large blocks of contiguous memory. It is clear that you are likely to run into trouble if memory fragmentation comes into play, which in most cases cannot be excluded for sure (especially in large projects designed as services or the like).

Recently I came accross the [ITK](http://www.itk.org/) image processing library and realized, that they (virtually) always allocate image data (even 3D - which might be huge) as one contiguous block. I was told that this should not be a problem, at least for 64 bit processes. However, I don't see a systematic difference between 64 bit and 32 bit processes besides the fact that memory problems might occurr delayed due to the larger virtual address space.

To come to the point: I wonder what is good practice when dealing with large amounts of data: Simply allocate it as one big block, or better split it up into smaller pieces for allocation?

As the question is of course rather system specific I would like to restrict it to native (unmanaged, no CLR) C++ especially under windows. However, I would be also interested in any more general comments - if possible.

Comment: Even if it is the only difference, delayed by a factor of 2^32 is pretty significant. It means that a long running process which previously ran into memory fragmentation problems after 1 minute, now runs into problems after 8000 years. Without wishing to get all Y2K about it, problems that don't manifest until 8000 years uptime are not problems. Or at least not *my* problem.

Comment: Doubling the address size doesn't get you twice the space, but the  space squared. So the problems will come *a lot* later on a 64 bit system.

Comment: People who resort to writing their own allocators do so because of two reasons: 1. They are misguided, 2. This is the absolute last resort after lots of profiling, and thorough understanding of the limitations of the default memory management system. So which category do you fall into? My point, use the system memory manager, unless this is proven to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @Nim Depending on what you're doing, how you manage memory can make a significant difference.  Allocating image data in one contiguous block, rather than fragmenting it, simplifies access and improves locality, both of which can make a significant difference in performance.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I don't disagree, but writing your own memory manager is a non trivial task, if you can get away with using the default - I'd say it's always the better option (?)

Comment: @Nim You don't have to write your own manager.  IIUC, the image data is logically one big (structured?) block.  It's probably easier to allocate it in a single `new` than to separate it into chunks.  (Before I'd write my own memory manager, I'd look around for alternative implementations of `malloc` on the net.)

Comment: @SteveJessop, I get your point. The point of my question was to find out which is the "cleaner" (= better practice) way of handling things.

Comment: @James: and before I'd look for alternative implementations of malloc on the net, I'd use a `deque`. Lazy, but hopefully the good kind of lazy :-)

Answer (score 6):

The question almost seems nonsensical... let me rephrase it to illustrate:

> If you need a large block of memory and are worried about fragmentation, should you just fragment it yourself?

You don't gain anything by fragmenting it yourself rather than letting the system memory manager fragment it for you. The system is extremely good at this, and you are not likely to do it better.

That being said, if all things being equal you can do the same task but broken into sensible fragments, it may be worth profiling to see if you can gain anything. But in general, you won't gain anything in a reasonable sense -- you won't be able to outperform the OS.

Comment: My point in splitting large memory blocks would not be to accelerate fragmentation ( ;) ), but a (maybe too?) simple thinking: In fragmented memory I can still allocate a chunk of small memory blocks, but I might not be able to allocate a large block.

Comment: Ah you're concerned about the memory manager not having enough *virtual* address space to even fulfill your requests, not physical memory fragmentation. In this case though I still think the question is a bit strange, because you already know the solution, you're just asking whether you should do it or not. I think you can answer that better than anyone else, but I think everyone would agree that you should avoid fixing a problem that hasn't been proven to exist. Make certain the fix is actually worth the overall cost.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. One thing I really understood now from the discussion here (admittedly I had not before) is the severe difference between 32 bit and 64 bit processes in this regard. From our experience the "slicing" of memory is absolutely neccessary for us if the software runs under 32 bit - but in the future we might ommit it as soon as we are exclusively developing for 64 bit systems (which is, unfortunately, not yet the case).